# Spring Webflux - Reactive Cassandra - configure ConsistencyLevel

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-webflux

Question regarding SpringBoot Webflux with reactive Cassandra please.

In the previous non reactive world, we could configure ConsistencyLevel as follow:

```
CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration

    @Override
    public QueryOptions getQueryOptions() {
        QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
        queryOptions.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.TWO);
        return queryOptions;
    }
```

However, with AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration, it seems things changed.

```
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories
public class BaseCassandraConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration {

    @Override
    public QueryOptions getQueryOptions() {
        QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
        queryOptions.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.TWO);
        return queryOptions;
    }
```

- There is an issue on the @Override, "Method does to override from super class"
- And the implementation of QueryOptions seems to have changed.

What is the correct way to configure the consistency level in Spring Webflux 2.3.5 + reactive Cassandra please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the consistency level on the auto configured Session instance by using the following property

```
spring.data.cassandra.consistencyLevel
```